# sending email via ms gragh core api python

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am using msgraphApi python,
I am able to read the mail box contents using ClientSecretConfidential ie providing
tenant_id , client_id,  client_secret

however while trying to send the email
the provided scope must have a scope input parameter, even when the scope is passed.

even for get token, i am getting the same error , that scope needs to passed.

client_secret_credential.get_token(scopes=['Mail.Send'])

Can we send email without using token.

Comment: Could you please share the code that you are using to get the token?

Comment: @shivaKeshavVarma, gave the extra details you requested for.

Comment: Check [these samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?products=ms-graph&languages=python) and modify your code according to your requirement

Comment: it did not help either, infact it something similar i had done earlier too

Answer (score 0):

The scope here is actually not the scope of permissions but rather the scope of application. I always use the following

```
myscopes: list = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
```

Then

```
client_secret_credential.get_token(scopes=myscopes)
```